# Can't set properties for Annotation Processing for RequestFactory Validation

Tags: android, requestfactory, annotation-processing

Many stackoverflow questions link to

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation#IDE_configuration

which shows a place to set "Annotation Processing" properties under "Java Compiler"

but my Eclipse 3.7 setup does not have an option for "Annotation Processing" in the preferences under Java Compiler.

Any idea why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Annotation Processing" is not available if you go into the **general** preferences for all projects.  I finally found that you must go into the specific project preferences by right clicking on your project, then choose "Properties".  Then you can see "Annotation Processing" under Java Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Type on the search at the top left for "annotation" and you should see it. On my setup it is under Errors/Warnings under Java compiter

Comment: Thanks roboto1986, but these set of preferences don't include the important RequestFactory properties shown in the link.  This RequestFactory validation stuff is so intermittent and drives me crazy!